# With Docker USER directive, multiple shell command run into permission problems

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've browsed a couple of articles about Docker best practices, and recognize that running a container as a non-privileged user has some obvious security bonuses.  So my first question is:  why use the `USER` directive at all to build your image?  That is, why not simply build the image as `root`, but `run` the container as a restricted user?  In that case, it seems `USER` is superfluous.

The story does not end there.  I tried various use-cases with `USER`.  As I am building an image based off a debian snapshot, I placed `USER` after all relevant `apt-get` installations.  So far so good.  But as soon as I tried creating content within the `USER`'s home directory, permission issues surfaced -- no matter if I explicitly assigned `USER` and group permissions to the enclosing parent directory.

Whenever I run into a feature that does not work in the obvious way, I ask myself whether it is a feature worth keeping.  So, is there any practical reason to retain `USER`, given that you probably could do everything in a user-restricted way -- at least from a permissions perspective -- from outside the container?

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons to run things as a non-root user (Docker or otherwise) is as an additional layer of security: even if your application is somehow compromised, it can't overwrite its own source code or static content that it's serving to end users.  I would generally include a `USER` directive, but only at the very end so that it only affects the (default) user for the `docker run` command.

```sh
FROM some-base-image
...
# Do all installation as root
...
# And pick an alternate user for runtime only
USER something
CMD ["the_app"]
```

"Home directory" isn't really a Docker concept.  It's very typical to store your application in, say, `/app` (mode 0755 owned by root).

Comment: I'm using `BuildKit` for purposes of accessing a private git-repo through SSH.  So I require the `RUN` option `--mount=type=ssh` for purposes of appropriating SSH credentials from the host agent while concurrently shielding those credentials from the Dockerfile.  To pull it off, Docker documentation lists an example that writes `~/.ssh/known_hosts`; hence my implicit use of $HOME directory.